# navigation controller is not working suspiciously

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I've been using the code below to go to another VCs in swift for the past 2 months I've been learning swift.

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VerifyVC") as!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

but now as I want to use it again in another project, it does not work!!! 
does anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of you should test to make sure that the navigationController ain't nil as mentioned by Sh_Khan.

If it is nil then you might want to add it.

```
 let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VerifyVC") as!

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: next)
self.present(viewController: navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This will cause you to create a new navigationcontroller and embedd the `next` viewController inside of it and then push the navigationController.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

It's probably that the vc you run this code

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

inside is not embedded inside a navigationController , so this

```
self.navigationController
```

is **nil**

hence no push happens